# how to get geolocation permissions in javascript manifest?

Tags: javascript, android, html

i have this manifest.webapp:

```
{
"version": "5.0",
"name": "Geo Rutas",
"description": "Geo Rutas con memoria instalacion package",
"launch_path": "/geoRoutes.html",

"icons": {
    "16":  "/ico_16.png",
    "48":  "/ico_48.png",
    "128": "/ico_128.png"
},

"developer": {
    "name": "Jota Montoyo",
    "url": "http://internetng.dit.upm.es"
},

"permissions": {
    "geolocation": { 
        "description": "Requerido para el autocompletado en la pantalla compartida" 
    },
    "systemXHR": {
        "description": "Required to make Network calls"
    }
}
```

}

It works even in my desktop and in the emulator, but not in an Android mobile.

Thank's in advanced for help.

Answer (score 0):

Add following in manifest.xml below `<uses-sdk/>` and above `<application/>`

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: thank you Ajeet, but your solution is for an android project, for its xml manifest. My question is about the geolocation permissions for a manifes.webapp for html5. I can make the webapp instalation, but it doesn't work in android mobiles. Sorry for my english, is not too good.

Comment: Sorry for that, I didn't noticed.